# Can I crop an image using settings from another image in Photoshop camera raw?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, crop, tiff

I have about 16,000 tiff images with size of each file is about 250MB,
cropping them using camera raw would take forever because of the size. The crop is not the same for all images.

I'm thinking of a solution like this:

1. Convert tiff files to another type, for example .jpg, keeping dimension, file names, etc.
2. Use camera raw to draw the rectangle I want to crop. It would take less time because the size is much smaller.

Is it possible to use the .jpg files with drawn rectangle to output the tiffs?

I'm using Photoshop CS6.

Answer (score 1):

If the crop is exactly the same for every image, then you could simply record an Action to crop a TIFF, and export as JPEG, and apply the Action using *File > Automate > Batch*, on an entire folder full of TIFF files. There's no need to used Adobe Camera RAW for this.

If the crop isn't the same for each image, then it will require a human to do it manually for each one.

Comment: thank for answering, but if the crop is the same for every image, I just need to apply setting for the 1st one, then output, no need to load anything, the problem here is i have to adjust each image. it already took a long time, the file size make it worse...

Comment: If you have to adjust each image, then it will take a long time.  There's no way for Photoshop to adjust crops automatically. It doesn't know anything about choosing where to crop.  You might be quicker using Lightroom to crop lots of images - but it will still be a manual process if each crop is different. It's easy enough in Lightroom to export all the images in one go as jpegs.

Comment: Furthermore, a crop is not a setting in an image file, it's a command executed by software to make a physical change to the size of the image.